# Powershell - ComboBox Calender

Tags: powershell, combobox, calendar

i wrote a script for get-messagetrackinglog.
I added a gui for recipients, sender, starttime etc.
And now i want to add a calendar to chose the date for start and end instead of tying it manually.
Im trying to do this with a combobox. So, the calendar pops up when i click on the arrow from the combobox. 
So far, i have a calendar but i dont know how to implement that into my combobox.

I already tried to    $comboBox.Items.Add("$objCalendar").
But this is not working at all. The Output for this is "System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar, SelectionRange: Start: 23.05.2017 00:00:00, End: 23.05.2017 00:00:00"

I think i need a parameter for $objCalender._ , but i couldnt find anything.

Any tips, please.

Answer (score 0):

I used DateTimePicker instead of ComboBox+MonthCalendar and its working now!